# adjustFontSizeToFitWidth on multiple UIViews while having the same minimum font size (swift 4.2)

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have multiple UILabels with different text inside them. I have a custom label with the property adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth set equal to true and numberOfLines set to 0. This causes the font to size of each label to take up the entire UILabel. The issues is that due to the different font sizes, each UILabel has a different font. Additionally, the font wraps to the next line in some cases. Here are two pictures of the behavior thats going on. [Using numberOfLines = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6X2k.png) [Using numberOfLines = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o2ib.png)

```
class MyCustumLabel: UILabel {
    let fontSize : CGFloat = 3000

    init(text: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.text = text
        self.font = UIFont.init(name: myFont, size: fontSize)
        self.numberOfLines = 1
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.textAlignment = .center
        self.textColor = .white
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

What I would like is for each of the UILabels text to find the largest font size that will fit its respective view, while only being on one line. I then need to take the smallest font of all the labels and apply that font to each of the middle label. This would cause all of the UILabels fonts to be the maximum size possible on one line while all being uniform with each other.

I thought about getting the font size of each label using label.fontSize after its been adjusted but it just returns the assigned font size of 3000. I can not find a way to retrieve the text size after it has been adjusted for the widths.

I've also tried using minimumScaleFactor with no success.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference but each view is being held inside of a stack view. I thought about using a table view to hold the views but this is the approach I went with.

Any help would be much appreciated.